# How to show dates in pivot table as a regular table? (excel) pivot table

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Does anyone know how can i turn this [image]

into this within pivot table?

[image]

Comment: Right click > pivot table options > display tab > check "Classic PivotTable layout"

Comment: Set Design format to Tabular.